# What is apt-check and why does it run during boot?

Tags: 11.10, boot, apt

So during one of the sessions at UDS-P, I discovered this cool (and useful) program called bootchart.

After installing it and then running it, I analyzed it and compared it some of the results [here](http://people.canonical.com/~pitti/bootcharts/).  There is a program running during boot called "apt-check," for somewhere in the ballpark of 40 seconds and it's using a lot of CPU.  Which makes me ask these 2 questions:

1. What is apt-check?
2. Why does it run during boot?

I am running the on a single-core Atom processor (N270), dual-boot machine running Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows XP Home.

Answer (score 8):

One of the services started at boot time from `upstart` is `mounted-run` (as you can see in `/etc/init/`). The comment at start of the file says:

> ```
> # mounted-run - Populate and link to /run filesystem
> #
> # Populates the /run filesystem and adds compatibility links to it
> ```

Among other things, it executes:

```
run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
```

i.e., executes every script in `/etc/update-motd.d` to update the message that you see when you log-in to a textual console, or through ssh (motd = message of the day). This message also says if there are packages to be upgraded and if a reboot is required.

In this dir you find the script `90-updates-available` that in turn calls

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available
```

that, based on a timestamp, calls `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check`.
This python script update the repositories, so it take some time to execute, but depending on the timestamp of the last update, it is not always executed at boot.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this apt-check thing from happening every time my boot up my Netbook?  It might save me some boot time.

Comment: turn off the motd script entirely and you'll save a few cycles.  You could comment out the line in mounted-run or you could remove the scripts from /etc/update-motd.d/ or you could make them as not executable. Maybe there is a better way to do it, but those should all work.